# ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations

Tags: python, opencv, lbph-algorithm

Running the code of linear binary pattern for Adrian. This program runs but gives the following warning:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py:922: ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations.
 "the number of iterations.", ConvergenceWarning
```

I am running python2.7 with opencv3.7, what should I do?

Comment: in LogisticRegression algorithm deafult iteration is 100. increase it if your dataset samples more than 100.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Normally when an optimization algorithm does not converge, it is usually because the problem is not well-conditioned, perhaps due to a poor scaling of the decision variables. There are a few things you can try.

1. Normalize your training data so that the problem hopefully becomes more well
   conditioned, which in turn can speed up convergence. One
   possibility is to scale your data to 0 mean, unit standard deviation using
   [Scikit-Learn's
   StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)
   for an example. Note that you have to apply the StandardScaler fitted on the training data to the test data. Also, if you have discrete features, make sure they are transformed properly so that scaling them makes sense.
2. Related to 1), make sure the other arguments such as regularization
   weight, `C`, is set appropriately. `C` has to be > 0. Typically one would try various values of `C` in a logarithmic scale (1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3, ..., 1, 10, 100, ...) before finetuning it at finer granularity within a particular interval. These days, it probably make more sense to tune parameters using, for e.g., Bayesian Optimization using a package such as [Scikit-Optimize](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/).
3. Set `max_iter` to a larger value. The default is 1000. This should be your last resort. If the optimization process does not converge within the first 1000 iterations, having it converge by setting a larger `max_iter` typically masks other problems such as those described in 1) and 2). It might even indicate that you have some in appropriate features or strong correlations in the features. Debug those first before taking this easy way out.
4. Set `dual = True` if number of features > number of examples and vice versa. This solves the SVM optimization problem using the dual formulation.  Thanks [@Nino van Hooff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923557/nino-van-hooff) for pointing this out, and @JamesKo for spotting my mistake.
5. Use a different solver, for e.g., the L-BFGS solver if you are using Logistic Regression. See [@5ervant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007055/5ervant)'s answer.

**Note: One should not ignore this warning.**

This warning came about because

1. Solving the linear SVM is just solving a quadratic optimization problem. The solver is typically an iterative algorithm that keeps a running estimate of the solution (i.e., the weight and bias for the SVM).
   It stops running when the solution corresponds to an objective value that is optimal for this convex optimization problem, or when it hits the maximum number of iterations set.
2. If the algorithm does not converge, then the current estimate of the SVM's parameters are not guaranteed to be any good, hence the predictions can also be complete garbage.

**Edit**

In addition, consider the comment by [@Nino van Hooff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/923557/nino-van-hooff) and [@5ervant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007055/5ervant) to use the dual formulation of the SVM. This is especially important if the number of features you have, D, is more than the number of training examples N. This is what the dual formulation of the SVM is particular designed for and helps with the conditioning of the optimization problem. Credit to [@5ervant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007055/5ervant) for noticing and pointing this out.

Furthermore, [@5ervant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007055/5ervant) also pointed out the possibility of changing the solver, in particular the use of the L-BFGS solver. Credit to him (i.e., upvote his answer, not mine).

I would like to provide a quick rough explanation for those who are interested (I am :)) why this matters in this case. Second-order methods, and in particular approximate second-order method like the L-BFGS solver, will help with ill-conditioned problems because it is approximating the Hessian at each iteration and using it to scale the gradient direction. This allows it to get better convergence *rate* but possibly at a higher compute cost per iteration. That is, it takes fewer iterations to finish but each iteration will be slower than a typical first-order method like gradient-descent or its variants.

For e.g., a typical first-order method might update the solution at each iteration like

```
x(k + 1) = x(k) - alpha(k) * gradient(f(x(k)))
```

where alpha(k), the step size at iteration k, depends on the particular choice of algorithm or learning rate schedule.

A second order method, for e.g., Newton, will have an update equation

```
x(k + 1) = x(k) - alpha(k) * Hessian(x(k))^(-1) * gradient(f(x(k)))
```

That is, it uses the information of the local curvature encoded in the Hessian to scale the gradient accordingly. If the problem is ill-conditioned, the gradient will be pointing in less than ideal directions and the inverse Hessian scaling will help correct this.

In particular, L-BFGS mentioned in [@5ervant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2007055/5ervant)'s answer is a way to approximate the inverse of the Hessian as computing it can be an expensive operation.

However, second-order methods might converge much faster (i.e., requires fewer iterations) than first-order methods like the usual gradient-descent based solvers, which as you guys know by now sometimes fail to even converge. This can compensate for the time spent at each iteration.

In summary, if you have a well-conditioned problem, or if you can make it well-conditioned through other means such as using regularization and/or feature scaling and/or making sure you have more examples than features, you probably don't have to use a second-order method. But these days with many models optimizing non-convex problems (e.g., those in DL models), second order methods such as L-BFGS methods plays a different role there and there are evidence to suggest they can sometimes find better solutions compared to first-order methods. But that is another story.

Comment: I am seeing that warning in this notebook:

https://www.kaggle.com/ninovanhooff/svm-for-fraud-detection

Note that it seems to be that all variables used for train and test are normalized

I did not set any classifier parameters though, but unsure of what values of C to use. Should I set C based on my investigation of the coefficients? (See the bar plot in that notebook)

Comment: Answer to my previous comment: As suggested by the scikit docs, I set dual to false. This removed the warning and seemed to have no influence on classification performance

Comment: @PJRobot You are welcome. But also consider my other comments about setting the regularization parameter and standardizing the variables. Usually the optimization algorithm should not take too many iterations to converge. If it does, then it is a sign that the optimization problem is ill-conditioned. Setting the regularization parameter and scaling the data appropriately, or solving the dual of the optimization problem as suggested by Nino van Hooff, are better ways to "fix" this problem which you should consider before you try changing `max_iter`.

Comment: I'm confused, according to the documentation it says `Prefer dual=False when n_samples > n_features.` Did you get it backwards?

Comment: @JamesKo Yes, I made a mistake. I should have wrote set `dual = True` if number of features > number of samples. The reason is in the dual formulation of the SVM, the number of parameters is the same as the number of samples, whereas in the primal formulation, the number of parameters is the number of features + 1. So if there are much fewer samples than features, then the dual formulation will solve a "smaller" optimization problem.

Comment: I had some models working well but after the library changed from sklearn to scikit-learn, I got this error very often. I could "fix" the warning increasing the iterations and it worked in any case. max_iter = 5000 saved me of doing something else.

Answer (score 39):

I reached the point that I set, up to `max_iter=1200000` on my `LinearSVC` classifier, but still the *"ConvergenceWarning"* was still present. I fix the issue by just setting `dual=False` and leaving `max_iter` to its default.

With `LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')` classifier, you should increase `max_iter`. Mine have reached `max_iter=7600` before the *"ConvergenceWarning"* disappears when training with large dataset's features.

Comment: Setting `dual` depending on the shape of my data helped in my case.

Comment: LinearSVC dual=True converged properly

According to sklearn LinearSVC docs.
"Select the algorithm to either solve the dual or primal optimization problem. Prefer dual=False when n_samples > n_features."

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html

Answer (score 17):

Explicitly specifying the `max_iter` resolves the warning as the default `max_iter` is 100. [For Logistic Regression].

```
 logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
```

Answer (score 8):

Please incre max_iter to 10000 as default value is 1000. Possibly, increasing no. of iterations will help algorithm to converge. For me it converged and solver was -'lbfgs'

```
log_reg = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',class_weight='balanced', max_iter=10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the warnings if you would not like to see them.

```
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import ConvergenceWarning

# Ignore ConvergenceWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category = ConvergenceWarning)
```