# Cross_Val_Score returning nan

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

EDITED:
I am using the below code. I am using average precison as metric. In the below code, in print statement I am getting nan calues for accuracy. But when I use different datset, it is working fine. I tried to pass data as array, even then I am getting nan values. Can anyone explain me what is happening.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import hyperopt
from hyperopt import tpe
from hyperopt import STATUS_OK
from hyperopt import Trials
from hyperopt import hp
from hyperopt import fmin
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


def hyperopt_train_test(params):
    cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 1, test_size = .25, random_state = 0 ) 
    clf =LogisticRegression(**params)

    return cross_val_score(clf,  df.loc[:,:'Amount'], df['Class'],cv = cv,scoring='average_precision').mean()

space = {
    'C' : hp.uniform('C', 0.05, 1000),
    'penalty': hp.choice('penalty',['l2','l1']),
    'max_iter':hp.choice('max_iter',[200,300,400,500])
}

def f(params,scores=[]):
    acc = hyperopt_train_test(params)
    print(acc, "Accuracy")
    scores.append(acc)
    return {'scores':scores,'loss': 1-acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'scores':scores}

trials = Trials()
trials
best = fmin(f, space, algo=tpe.suggest, max_evals=10, trials=trials)
print('best:',best)
hyperopt.space_eval(space,best)
```

[The Dataset can be loaded here](https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud)

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to be working fine. I ran it without making any changes to the dateset and loading it in with pandas. My guess would be, if you did any did manipulation, that data types might have gotten changed. I'd double check to make sure everything is as expected. I did however notice that you get some `ConvergenceWarnings` when running. You can read up on how to fix those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670012/convergencewarning-liblinear-failed-to-converge-increase-the-number-of-iterati)

Comment: HI Tyler, Strange. Sometimes I get nan. I modified parameters and I am getting nans again. I have eedited my code. Could you please re-run once.. I am not understanding the issue here....