# How to set a right max_iter value in sklearn LinearSVC to avoid Convergence Warning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, liblinear

I refereed to [this discussion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52670012/convergencewarning-liblinear-failed-to-converge-increase-the-number-of-iterati/60127215#60127215). As mentioned in this discussion I normalised my data and set dual = False in LinearSVC . Initially I set the max_iter to  default(1000) received the ConvergenceWarning and then I set max_iter to 70000 still received the warning.

How to come up with a right max_iter value. My dataset size is 6000 and feature vary from 1000 to 6000(used RBF kernel approximation).